# THIS reference is failing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code:

```
Drupal.behaviors.articleQuiz = (function(){
    var _attach = function(context){
            $('.question-container', context)
                    // .once()
                    .each(function(i, section){
                            new ArticleQuiz($(section));
                    });
    };

    return {
            attach: _attach
    };
})();

function ArticleQuiz($el){
    this.$el = $el;
    this.answer = this.$el.data('answer');
    console.log('this.answer', this.answer);
    this.quizLogic();
    return this;
}

ArticleQuiz.prototype.quizLogic = function(){
    var THIS = this;

    $('.quiz-cols a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // exit if choice already made: users can't change their pick
        if ($(this).parents('.quiz-cols').parent().find('.white-font').length) {
            return;
        }

        // set class according to data-answer:
        $(this).addClass('background-' + (THIS.answer === true ? 'green' : 'red')).addClass('white-font');
        console.log('answer', THIS.answer)
    });
    return THIS;
};

Drupal.behaviors.articleQuiz.attach($body);
```

In the function `ArticleQuiz()` you may see a `console.log('this.answer', this.answer);` which prints this and it's totally correct:

[image]

And then almost at the you may see this other `console.log('answer', THIS.answer)` which is within the `click` function and prints only `true`. Which means that is ignoring the other 2 `false`s that you might see in the picture I put above.

This is the html:

```
<div data-answer="true" class="question-container">
    <div>
      <h2>1. First question.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="quiz-cols">
      <div class="true-placeholder">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="quiz-cols">
      <div class="false-placeholder">...</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-answer="false" class="question-container">
    <div>
      <h2>2. Second question.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="quiz-cols">
      <div class="true-placeholder">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="quiz-cols">
      <div class="false-placeholder">...</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-answer="false" class="question-container">
    <div>
      <h2>3. Third question.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="quiz-cols">
      <div class="true-placeholder">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="quiz-cols">
      <div class="false-placeholder">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And just for you to know, the `this.$el = $el;` is pointing to `div.question-container`

As you see in that html there are 3 `div`s with class and data attribute `data-answer="true" class="question-container"`, one of them is with `data-answer=true` and the other 2 are with `data-answer=false`.

So my question. Why in the first console.log I can see the 3 data-answer attributes coming up as they are: 1 true and 2 false. And in the click function it doesn't matter the container I click on, it only returns 3 `true` and ignores the `false`?

**EDIT**
The reference is working properly out of the click function.

Comment: So where/how is `ArticleQuiz` instantiated?

Comment: @Pointy I have added some more code.

Comment: I'd move `var THIS = this;` to `function ArticleQuiz($el)`

Comment: @KScandrett - it's not needed there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a click handler for all the questions every time `this.quizLogic()` is called, instead of only for the current question. You can fix that by adding context to the selector before attaching the handler:

```
$('.quiz-cols a', this.$el).click(function(e) {
   ...
```